# get accents preg_match_all grammar PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this preg_match_all to get hashtags:

```
  preg_match_all('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/ui', $text, $matchedHashtags);
```

it works nice, but stops if find some accentuation:

```
#hash //works
#hash_hash //works
#hash_não // get just $hash_n
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Unicode category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) `Letter`.

- <kbd>**`\p{L}`**</kbd> Matches letters from all [Unicode scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)) (≅ languages).

**Regex:**

```
/(?<![\p{L}0-9_])#([\p{L}0-9_]+)/u
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM4pO1/1)</kbd>

- Another option is to simply include the accented characters in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

  ```
  /(?<![a-zãàÀèÈìÌ0-9_])#([a-zãàÀèÈìÌ0-9_]+)/ui
  ```

---

**<sub>[Edit]</sub>**

---

## About `\p` tokens

[php](/questions/tagged/php) supports Unicode when the `/u` flag is set. There are some alternatives to match letters, using the following categories or scripts:

#### 1. `\p{Latin}` Latin Script

- Matches: [Latin script characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) from English, French, German, Italian, Vietnamese, Latin itself, and several other languages (including some modifier letters and other letters).
- Codepoints: 1,349

#### 2. `\p{L&}` Caseless Letters

- Matches: [Lowercase_Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm), [Uppercase_Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm) and [Titlecase_Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm).
- Codepoints: 3,646 (1,984 + 1,631 + 31)

#### 3. `\p{L}` All Letters

- Matches: `\p{L&}`, [Other_Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm) and [Modifier_Letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm).
- Codepoints: 18,057 (3,646 + 14,163 + 248)

#### 4. `\p{Xan}` Any alphanumeric character

- Matches: `\p{L}` and [`\p{N}` Number](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm) (from any script).
- Codepoints: 18,843 (18,057 + 786)

#### 5. `\p{Xwd}` Any Perl "word" character

- Matches: `\p{Xan}` and underscore.
- Codepoints: 18,844

Comment: or use `\p{Latin}` if you want to reduce the character class to latin characters.

Comment: @PaulCrovella You're probably referring to the [Unicode equivalent `decomposed form`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), where you can match [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) such as [`\p{Mn}`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm). I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @PaulCrovella That's true. You're right about that.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
(^|\w)#(\w+)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tT5lS3/1)

with u,g, and m modes